# Downloading a file after a page load in Pentaho Kettle (Data integration)

Tags: pentaho, etl, google-ads-api

I need to download a report (Google adwords) but Google only gives a URL to a website that after some seconds downloads the file to the computer (there's no url to the file).

I use the 'http' method to reach the website but I don't know how to capture the file that is downloaded. Any idea on how?

I'm using Pentaho Kettler 5.4.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you get the file with `wget` or `curl`? Both of these have a -O (output file) option where you can specify the file name.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately that doesn't work because the report is not withing the url that Google gives me but rather it opens a website and after X seconds it downloads a file to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

use dev tools in chrome or firebug in firefox and you'll be able to find out the url of the file that is being downloaded.